# Using Date and Time Picker in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I am using Angular JS. I want to add date and time controls in the Index.cshtml page with following conditions:

1. The form should show "start date" control, which should pick date.
2. "End date" control which should pick date.
3. "Start time" control which should pick time.
4. "End time" control which should pick time.
5. By default, start date should show current date. End date should be 1 day plus the start date.
6. start date should not be in the past date, and end date should not be less than start date.
7. The controls should follow "en-US" format.
8. start time should show current time.
9. Date controls should have a placeholder of "MM/DD/YYYY"
10. The time controls should have a placeholder "HH:MM:SS"

How to use a date and time picker control in Angular Js?

Comment: As you are already using `Angular`, you can use `Angular-UI bootstrap date picker` for that : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Hi. I need a date and time picker, with the conditions as "By default, start date should show current date. End date should be 1 day plus the start date. start date should not be in the past date, and end date should not be less than start date. The controls should follow "en-US" format. start time should show current time. Date controls should have a placeholder of "MM/DD/YYYY" and the time controls should have a placeholder "HH:MM:SS" "

Comment: You can set those options using the directive.